# How is this not checkmate? I had loads of time to spare

Tags: checkmate

See below my game last night, I am white and I got 3 queens. He only has the king left. We have loads of time left. It was a 30min game.

As soon as I moved my original queen up one space and got him into check mate, the game ended as a draw!

How is this a draw?

[image]

Comment: Your screen had the reason... Game drawn by stalemate...

Comment: I didn't realise that was the rules I thought if he cant move then thats a win anyway. Every day is a school day. But it is obvious now.

Comment: In this situation, you should try to make sure that each move delivers check. With three queens, it's not difficult at all to deliver checkmate without having any non-check moves.

Comment: @Acccumulation In fact, with 2 queens vs a lone king is at most mate in 4. With all the extra time, I'd say one would be better off taking the time to learn how to perform that mate instead of getting an extra queen. When I was in grade school I did something similar and was not-exactly-scolded-but-you-know by a coach, he said "Don't play with your food." I didn't even really play much after that but I took that lesson to heart!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A necessary condition for checkmate is that the king is in check, which is not the case here.

The position in question is called [stalemate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalemate): black does not have any legal moves, but is not in check. The game ends at this point, and is evaluated as a draw.

Comment: Of course this makes perfect sense. Thanks for pointing out the obvious now.

Answer (score 2):

It is stalemate (opponent's king can't move anywhere and not in check). Your queen move last move doesn't check his king.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand what a stalemate is.  It is one of the ways a game is drawn.  A stalemate occurs when it is your turn to move but you have no legal move.  So if your king is not in check, but any move you make with it would put it in check, which is illegal, that is a stalemate, which is a draw. In the diagram showing your queen move from f4 to f5, you have not put the Black king in check.  And you left him with no legal move on his turn, so it was a draw by stalemate.